# Why doesn't npm install correctly build dependency from a fork of a package on npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, react-bootstrap

I have a project that uses an older version of [react-bootstrap](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/tree/v0.13.3)

in my package.json I had

```
"react-boostrap": "^0.13.3"
```

And there is a bug in there that is causing an issue, the fix for it is very simple so I forked the repo, rolled back to the commit for v0.13.3 doing:

```
git reset --hard <commit-hash>
```

made my 1 line fix, then force pushed back to my fork.

Then I updated my package.json in the main project to point to my fork:

```
"react-boostrap": "mygithubrepo/react-bootstrap"
```

I deleted the node_modules directory and ran `sudo npm cache clear` to make sure everything was nice and fresh. Then I ran `npm install` which did pull down my version of react-bootstrap from the repo.

However, the version it now pulls down isn't in the same format in the node_modules folder. Essentially, it doesn't seem as if it's built the project.

If I use:

```
"react-boostrap": "^0.13.3"
```

then the node_modules folder contains the built code like so:

```
+node_modules
--+react_bootstrap
----+utils
-----Acordion.js
etc.....
```

But when I point it to my forked version of the repo:

```
"react-boostrap": "mygithubrepo/react-bootstrap"
```

Then I get just the source repo structure in node modules (and it doesn't seem to be built)

```
+node_modules
--+react_bootstrap
----+docs
----+ie8
----+src
-------+utils
--------Acordion.jsx
........etc.....
----+tools
etc.....
```

Now when I reference react bootstrap using `require('react-bootstrap')` then it doesn't work (because the files haven't been built).

So what is different between me pointing to the file on npmjs rather than on github?  There isn't any prepublish/publish/postpublish script in react-bootstrap package.json so I'm not sure if they manually built it before pushing to npmjs.

Basically, I need to get my forked version automatically built when I run `npm install` on my main project. Any ideas?

**Edit 1**

The errors I get running `npm install` on the main project repo after updating my fork of react-bootstrap as per Jonathan Muller's answer below:

```
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-uglify" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-amd-wrap" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-react" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-clean" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-watch" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-copy" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-browserify" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-requirejs" not found. Is it installed?
Warning: Task "clean:amd" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Answer (score 2):

In your package.json, add the following to build it when you npm install it:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "grunt build"
  }
}
```

This way the package will be built after install

Then to get it working with require, add the following to the package.json:

```
{
  "main": "amd/react-bootstrap.js"
}
```

So the correct file can be found when you "require" it. Otherwise it search for index.js

Comment: Thanks for that, I've added it. and whilst the `grunt build` task now runs on the dependency when I run `npm install` on the main project. I now get a bunch of errors because grunt build is being called within that dependency... `grunt build` builds successfully when I run it on my forked version of react-bootstrap

Comment: npm build doesn't produce anything... I tried `npm run build` but that just calls the grunt build command.... I also attempted to do `npm install && grunt build` hoping the dependencies would be installed, but it gets stuck in an infinite loop trying to install itself over and over again  - (You deleted your comment - now I look crazy! :p)

Comment: (Yes sorry because I was wrong :x)
Maybe a solution could be to commit the builded file in your repo (amd folder, or create a dist folder) and just use the "main" attribute of the package.json

Comment: I ended up just including the built files (generated by the npmjs module) in my project code..... and just making local references...No point in forking it and having the fork have to worry about the compilation and then my project contain src and bundled code.